# How to use MultiKeyMap from Apache in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-collection

I have come across MultiKeyMap from Apache Commons and am interested in using it in Spring framework instead of using regular map as I have a need for double key map. Dpes anyone know how to use MultiKeyMap with Spring framework?

Comment: What do you mean, "use with"?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check, but I guess support for `MultiKeyMap` is not built-in Spring.

You would need to construct `MultiKey` instances as keys to be used with the normal `Map` interface methods. The most explicit way would be like this:

```
<map>
  <entry>
    <key><bean class="org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue.MultiKey">
      <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="KEY_0_REF"/></constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg index="1"><value>KEY_1_VALUE</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean></key>
    <value>YOUR_VALUE</value>
  </entry>
</map>
```

The Map produced by the `<map>` element is not a `MultiKeyMap`, so you would need to create that yourself:

```
<bean id="yourMultiKeyMap" class="org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap">
      <constructor-arg>
        <map>YOUR_MULTI-KEY_VALUE_PAIRS</map>
      </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

It works (tested it with Spring 3.0.5), but it's a hell lot of XML to be written.

Using the spring-util namespace, you can reduce the map creation part to this:

```
<beans xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"  ...>
...
<util:map id="yourMultiKeyMap" map-class="org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap">
  <entry>
    ...
  </entry>
</u:map>
...
</beans>
```

Is there a shorter way to create the `MultiKey` instances?

Also note that I could inject the `MultiKeyMap` created as a bean using the `@Autowired` annotation, but I could not inject a map `<util:map>` using the `@Autowired` annotation. I had to use the `@Resource` annotation from JSR-250.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In the <entry> tag, how could we define two keys? Could you help?

Comment: I don't know of a shorter way than explicitly constructing a bean of class `MultiKey` as the key, as shown in the first code fragment of the answer.